# After an OS update, should you remain logged in?

Tags: software-update

My recollection of past behavior of OS X updates is the following:

1. Update downloaded from within App Store. System reboots.
2. System installation (gray background, apple symbol, est. time to completion)
3. Login prompt screen

After updating to 10.11.3 today, however, there was no login step. After the gray installation screen, there was a brief black screen, and then my desktop was instantly restored. I was already logged in--as if I weren't logged out at all for the reboot, in fact--already reconnected to wifi (but severed from my VPN due to the reboot), and already connected to the App Store.

My basic question is, is this default behavior?

Addendum: am I taking crazy pills, or was this not the usual behavior before?  Is it due to a setting I can change (so I can require the login screen after a reboot regardless of the reason)? I guess I find it unsettling that a user account is "auto-logged" into following a reboot, even if that user initiated the system update that triggered that reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable automatic login from the User & Groups control Panel...

- System Prefs > Users & Groups
- Click the lock & supply your password to unlock
- Login options - set Automatic Login to Off

[image]